What was the foundation laid by the prophets and the apostles in Ephesians 2:20

“built on the foundation of the apostles and prophets, Christ Jesus himself being the cornerstone,”
‭‭Ephesians‬ ‭2‬:‭20‬ ‭

What is this foundation that the household of God is built upon?

Are none of these any use?  https://biblehub.com/commentaries/ephesians/2-20.htm

Only last week I read a 45 page booklet delving into this very question, Foundations Uncovered. Its subtitle is "The Apostolic Foundation of the Christian Church". All I can do here is summarize some main points.
First, the author establishes from scripture the fact of the foundation, as when Paul wrote in 1 Corinthians 3:10-17 that as a wise master-builder, he laid the only foundation that can be laid, namely, Christ. God is the architect - architekton. All solid 'building' of Christ's Church is done by Christ, using his 12 apostles, Matthew 16:18. It is the 12 apostles of Christ who are the 12 foundations of the wall of the heavenly city of God, New Jerusalem - Revelation 21:14. The apostolic church was built upon the foundation of the apostles and prophets, Jesus Christ himself being the chief cornerstone, as the text in question states.
The next main point is establishing what the foundation is not. Many assume that because the apostles and prophets laid it, all subsequent ages rest on it. But it is a moral and spiritual foundation, and each generation needs to avoid taking it for granted, thinking it is a past historical fact so they are built on it too. No, the need is to discern whether the contemporary church abides in the truth of the one and only foundation that has been laid by Christ's apostles - Jesus Christ. Or, have other men started to lay their own foundations to build what they claim is 'the true church'? The apostles preached, taught, and wrote the spiritual truths constituting the foundation, in the New Testament, "the faith which was once delivered unto the saints" Jude vs. 3. This has to be earnestly contended for, as others were already creeping in to distort it when Jude wrote.
The foundation of the faith, the Church, involved the prophets, hence the Old Testament is vital:

"Therefore thus saith the Lord God, Behold, I lay in Zion for a
foundation a stone, a tried stone, a precious corner stone, a sure
foundation: he that believeth shall not make haste." Isiah 28:16 [i.e. 'be ashamed' as when quoted in Romans 10:11]
K.J.V.

The apostle Peter wrote that Jesus was that stone, over which many would stumble and fall. 1 Peter 2:3-8 explains this in detail. Many would build on sand, not the rock. Solid foundation is only on faithful preaching of the gospel of Christ, which the apostles did. The apostolic foundation was laid for time and eternity within the apostles' lifetime, and other foundation can no man lay.
Then the booklet goes on to detail how that foundation is described in scripture, namely as:
The word of Christ; true doctrine; the truth of the gospel, the faith of the New Testament, and then back to the true foundation, of which the author writes:

"The church, that is alone worthy the name, and heir to the benefits,
is built upon the apostolic foundation. However, this building is
spiritual, and also so is the foundation upon which it rests... The
building of foundations commences out of sight beneath the surface of
the earth, up from the rock which has been bared, to level with the
surface of the ground. Only such sound, stable and deep foundations
are able to take the weight of the successive stories to rise
thereupon...
This is in the spiritual sense precisely the function of the apostolic
foundation. Nothing but this foundation... can take the weight of the
church of God both for time and eternity; and nothing else bear the
stress when the rain of fiery judgment descends, and the floods of
vindictive wrath come, and the winds of furious vengeance blow, and
beat thereon...
The apostles have bared the rock from all that is of the earth, and
within a carefully defined area have dug down and built up the solid
foundation of apostolic doctrine. In their writings there is nothing
of the flesh or of the world or that is earthly; all has been
excavated. There remains solely what is of God. But not haphazardly
so... not upon what is merely traditional, ecclesiastical, historical,
national or geographical - all that must be excavated too (Eph.
2:20)...
The kind of slum of squatters' shacks in higgledy-piggledy chaos
independently littering the field today is evidence of not being built
on one foundation. But the one foundation once laid is the foundation
of God, 2 Timothy 2:19. It standeth sure. Abraham looked for it when he
sought a city which hath foundations, whose builder and maker is God
(Hebrews 11:10). And if Abraham's seed today look for the same, and not
at the things and churches which can be seen, they too shall discern
by faith as pilgrims what cannot be seen by sight as residents.
...Since at the beginning of the church these foundations of doctrine
were laid, and since at the end of the age in eternity nothing remains
in glory but what is above and upon these foundations, I say to my
soul, and to him that feareth God, Take heed how ye are built
thereon!" Foundations Uncovered, pages 35-37, John Metcalfe, 1983
http://www.johnmetcalfepublishingtrust.co.uk/contact_us.htm


+1 ... it's a good answer, but I think the prophets here are not those of the OT. Rather they are the prophets of the early church (note that they are mentioned after the apostles.  OT prophets would be mentioned before these. )

@DanFefferman  Oh, yes, Christians with the gift of prophecy in the 1st century  would also be included, along with the apostles and the O.T. prophets. Christ and the apostles frequently quoted from the OT prophecies as a vital part of their teaching for the 1st century Church - to identify Christ as the Son of God, the Messiah, the One who builds his Church.


Psalm 118:22 --  The stone which the builders rejected Has become the
chief cornerstone.

In Matthew 21:33-45 Jesus told a parable to show the present religious leaders of Israel about their abject failure in accepting Jesus as the Messiah. The previous verses to this parable show Jesus was talking to this subject and to the religious leaders of his day.
When Jesus led his audience to see the horrors of the vineyard keepers' hatred of their master, the servants he spoke about represented the prophets of the OT (Matthew 23:31, James 5:10), who Jesus talked about when he said, "O Jerusalem, Jerusalem, the one who kills the prophets and stones those who are sent to her." These builders' of Israel have a history in their Israeli past strewn with their rebellion of God all the way back to their very beginning as they rejected of Moses' leadership in the wilderness (Acts 7; Exodus 32). Jesus even called them out in their rejection of Moses even then, centuries later - "For if you believed Moses, you would believe me because he wrote about me." (John 5:46)

Matthew 23:31 --  "Therefore you are witnesses against yourselves that
you are sons of those who murdered the prophets."


James 5:10 -- My brethren, take the prophets, who spoke in the name of
the Lord, as an example of suffering and patience.

The verse in Psalm 118:22 about the rejected cornerstone when used in the NT is in the context of God bringing the Gentiles into the covenants of promise with Israel through Christ. The further NT quotes from the apostles of the NT follow the same idea as Jesus' parable in Matthew 21: Israel's rebellion was leading to the Gentiles salvation. Paul wrote about this in Romans 9-11.
Jesus is the cornerstone, "the first stone set in the construction of a masonry foundation", since all of the scripture points to Jesus (Galatians 3:22-24). This 'facing stone' or 'first stone' was the goal of the Law of Moses (Hebrews 7:19, Hebrews 10:1) and the subject of the prophets of the OT (John 5:39). The law and the prophets spoke of Christ (Luke 24:44) and the apostles of the NT spoke of no other but Jesus as Lord and Savior.

Galatians 3:22-24 -- But the Scripture has confined all under sin,
that the promise by faith in Jesus Christ might be given to those who
believe. But before faith came, we were kept under guard by the law,
kept for the faith which would afterward be revealed. Therefore the
law was our tutor to bring us to Christ, that we might be justified by
faith.


Hebrews 7:19 -- for the law made nothing perfect; on the other hand,
there is the bringing in of a better hope, through which we draw near
to God.


Hebrews 10:1 --  For the law, having a shadow of the good things to
come, and not the very image of the things, can never with these same
sacrifices, which they offer continually year by year, make those who
approach perfect.


John 5:39 -- "You search the Scriptures, for in them you think you
have eternal life; and these are they which testify of Me."


Luke 24:44 -- Then He said to them, “These are the words which I spoke
to you while I was still with you, that all things must be fulfilled
which were written in the Law of Moses and the Prophets and the Psalms
concerning Me.”

While I believe my above understanding shows the apostles mean the NT apostles (scripture in the NT) and the prophets mean the OT prophets (the law and prophets) in Ephesians 2:20, Ephesians 3:5 shows a very good reason to an argument in favor of the NT apostles and prophets instead. Candidly, I cannot rule this possibility out.

Ephesians 2:20 --  having been built on the foundation of the apostles
and prophets, Jesus Christ Himself being the chief cornerstone,


Ephesians 3:5,6 --  ... which in other ages was not made known to the
sons of men, as it has now been revealed by the Spirit to His holy
apostles and prophets: that the Gentiles should be fellow heirs, of
the same body, and partakers of His promise in Christ through the
gospel ...

Perhaps both of these concepts are somehow true.
After some more inadvertent research tonight, I found this scripture from 2 Peter. From what I see, this appears to be a general way of thinking across the NT scriptures:

Dear friends, this is the second letter I’m writing to you. In both
letters I’m trying to refresh your memory. I want you to remember the
words spoken in the past by the holy prophets and what the Lord and
Savior commanded you through your apostles. (2 Peter 3:1,2)


You clearly lean toward the former based on the quantity of text allocated even if you don’t rule out the latter. I do appreciate your post. It has provided a lot of insight into the subject at hand. And I hope to bring to light through this question that often times this claimed foundation is assumed to be something other than what it was to Paul and the early Church. This leading to erroneous claims and extrapolations that make shipwreck of doctrinal standards in favor of preferred interpreters.

Before proceeding further, let me state as emphatically as possible the principle uttered by the great apostle Paul himself that:
1 Cor 3:11 - For no one can lay a foundation other than the one already laid, which is Jesus Christ.
Now, the record we have of this foundation laid by Jesus Christ is via the teaching of the apostles.  Thus, we have references to this:

Acts 2:42 - They devoted themselves to the apostles’ teaching and to the fellowship, to the breaking of bread and to prayer.
Acts 13:12 - When the proconsul saw what had happened, he believed, for he was astonished at the teaching about the Lord.
Acts 16:4 - As they went from town to town, they delivered the decisions handed down by the apostles and elders in Jerusalem for the people to obey.
Acts 28:31 - Boldly and freely he proclaimed the kingdom of God and taught about the Lord Jesus Christ.
2 Cor 11:3, 4 - I am afraid, however, that just as Eve was deceived by the serpent’s cunning, your minds may be led astray from your simple and pure devotion to Christ. For if someone comes and proclaims a Jesus other than the One we proclaimed, or if you receive a different spirit than the One you received, or a different gospel than the one you accepted, you put up with it way too easily.
1 Tim 2:7 - For this reason I was appointed as a preacher, an apostle, and a faithful and true teacher of the Gentiles. I am telling the truth; I am not lying about anything.

Thus, it is entirely consistent with NT teaching that NT theology is based on the teaching about Jesus Christ as conveyed to all Christians by the apostles and prophets of the NT as declared by Paul -

Eph 2:20 - built on the foundation of the apostles and prophets, with
Christ Jesus Himself as the cornerstone.

This is an allusion to Ps 118:22 and quoted by Jesus Himself in Matt 21:42, Mark 12:10 and Luke 20:17.  See also Acts 4:11, 1 Peter 2:6, 7.  Indeed, it is via the NT prophets that we know anything about Jesus at all!
As Ellicott correctly observes:

(20) Built upon the foundation of the apostles and prophets.—In
spite of much ancient and valuable authority, it seems impossible to
take “the prophets” of this verse to be the prophets of the Old
Testament. The order of the two words and the comparison of Ephesians
3:5; Ephesians 4:11, appear to be decisive—to say nothing of the
emphasis on the present, in contrast with the past, which runs through
the whole chapter.


You have made an excellent argument for only half the claim, namely the foundation laid by the apostles (of which Paul was not one and could not possibly qualify as one to have laid that foundation, though he was one to propagate it and build upon it, hence  why the tense is past tense and Paul was still very early on his missionary journey when the epistle to the Ephesians was written). So what about the prophets part? According to the link you shared the author does not seem to think the prophets were those of the OT lest I misunderstood.

Paul is called an apostle numerous times in the NT such as Rom 1:1, 11:13, 1 Cor 1:1, 9:1, etc.  He even says he is not inferior to the "super-apostles" in 2 Cor 12:11,

@Dottard, any time in the NT when prophets are named in the context of the foundation of Christ as the cornerstone, it is in regards to the OT prophets. I'll try an answer to see if I can make sense of this better.

@Dottard are you conflating preascension apostles with post ascension apostles. No one is denying that Paul was an apostle but I want to be more exact and state that he was a post ascension apostle, he was not and did not lay down the foundation. This is not about inferiority this is about precision and whether or not Paul is laying down the exact foundation that the preascension apostles laid or if he is laying down another, and I submit to you he is laying down the same foundation. Now if you think Paul not Matthias should have been the 12th why would the Holy Spirit agree with Matthias?

@NihilSineDeo - the NT makes not such distinction; quite the contrary.  If Paul, Jude, Mark and Luke are removed from the NT, what do we have?

@dottard I don’t know what point you are making in the second half of your comment. I’m assuming the erroneous assumption that apostles write Scripture, Whereas not all the apostles did wrote Scripture and not all who wrote in the NT were Apostles. But in fact the Bible does make the distinction between pre ascension and post ascension apostles. However I haven’t the space in this comment to make the case.
